# How do I make a line not return?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this website.(http://kristinbecker.com/everydaypart1_test.htm)

The client would like some space under the various jewelry pieces. How would I go about creaking a paragraph under the pieces but not have it return a line every time I create a new on. The length doesn't matter and the width is set. I just don't want the line to return. How would I go about doing this in html or css?

Pages: 
http://kristinbecker.com/everydaypart1_test.htm

http://kristinbecker.com/style.css

(Word of warning the Css might not match up, I took this job over from someone who was terminally ill. The Css sheet has some classes in it, but some are just embedded in the header of the individual pages.)

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: You might want to replace those images with smaller versions. Currently you have these huge JPEGs that are being scaled with the `img`'s `width` and `height` attributes.

Comment: took forever to load that page !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple in CSS after you've changed your HTML a bit. Your current structure is a little like this:

```
paragraph containing images
    first image
    second image
    third image
    fourth image
paragraph about first image
paragraph about second image
paragraph about third image
paragraph about fourth image
```

You can start by changing that to this:

```
unordered list
    list item
        image
        paragraph about image
    list item
        image
        paragraph about image
    list item
        image
        paragraph about image
    list item
        image
        paragraph about image
```

Now the images and their corresponding paragraphs are clearly linked. Now if the unordered list has the class `images`:

```
.images {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.images li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 155px;
    min-height: 500px; /* adjust this as you see fit */
    float: left;
}
```

Now you don't even have to separate the images by rows; CSS will lay it all out for you.

Comment: Thank you a bunch. The list idea is probably the best, but I guess because it was previously mentioned in the `paragraph containing images
    first image
    second image
    third image
    fourth image
paragraph about first image
paragraph about second image
paragraph about third image
paragraph about fourth image` format I was looking for a way to do as little to that as possible, but the list worked. Thanks a lot again. I just need to tweek it a bit.

Comment: @JackMcE: I thought the list idea would be better because it's a little more semantic; if someone was using a screen reader and you had `alt` attributes on the images, it would say something about the image and then its relevant paragraph instead of four images and four paragraphs in that order. Anyway, if this answer helped you, please accept it by checking the hollow checkmark next to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks I checked it off as help and I see your reasoning and its better than mine was. I'm semi new to this stuff and really like it, but some times things that probably shouldn't stump me get me.

Answer (score 1):

By "return" I assume you mean wrap.

`selector { whitespace: nowrap }`

Comment: The problem becomes that the width is removed. The idea is that the will just go next to each other on a horizontal line forever. Now it does this... http://kristinbecker.com/everydaypart1_test.htm

Comment: I completely misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at your page.

Add this to your `.underpics` class

```
display: inline-block;
```